# Apache2 Virtual Host Servername not working correctly

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

I have issues with my Apache2.4 Webserver. I have a domain registered @netcup and redirected it to the IP of my Webserver (using a friend's one so he already has his domains pointed there too)

Now I have my VirtualHost setup this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.holzbau-krüger.de
        ServerAdmin administrator@n-network.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/wg-manager
        <Directory /var/www/wg-manager/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I open the page it opens up his main page, which is reachable under his domain.

Any idea, what is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

If you enter the given ServerName test.holzbau-krüger.de into your browser, the browser will translate the domain name to a IDN domainname, like test.xn--holzbau-krger-5ob.de.

So you must name the virtual host not with test.holzbau-krüger.de but with test.xn--holzbau-krger-5ob.de

Please have a look at:

- https://www.denic.de/service/tools/idn-web-converter/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: Answer to question are supposed to be technical not "Google for it". Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer please

Comment: The problem is, that the domain holzbau-krüger.de should be written as a IDN Domain. There are hundreds of sites explaining, what IDN means. I could copy&paste all of that here or give the hint to search for IDN. I lke to help Jan, and I‘m sure my answer gave him the hint, what is wrong.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Maybe that is the problem: how can I clarify the question, when I cannot comment on it? How can I get reputation without guessing, because I cannot comment to clarify the question? ‘m still sure, that this is the real problem, because the ServerName will never hit to the request, because it isn’t a IDN. Maybe we all should stop guessing and wait for a response from the asker?

Comment: @TRW The last link provided by geisterfurz007 answers your questions about what to do istead of putting comments as answers. For gaining reputation points, ask questions, answer clear questions, or suggest edits.

Comment: @TRW edit your answer and improve it as indicated by previous commenter and the downvote can become upvote, that the principe of Stackoverflow

Comment: I‘m 100% sure, my answer is correct. You cannot use umlaut in ServerName. I gave the answer to look for IDN on the net. This is similar to your responses of sending howto links. There is no difference.

Comment: And to stop this offtopic discussion - please give your own answers to the question instead of criticizing other. That doesn’t help the asker too.